# Using a Node.JS module with an AngularJS web app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to build a simple web app using Angular JS, and would like to use functions from the [Node.JS scipy module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scipy). I'm a bit confused to how I would do this?

I've tried setting up a web server using Node, Express and SocketIO, but I'm not sure where I should be initialising the scipy module, and how do I use its function inside my app.js file for AngularJS.

I'm just a bit confused in general as to how one can use the different node modules in any web app using something like Angular JS. Ideally, I'd like to use the simplest and fastest way, so I can prototype different applications quickly.

Comment: Thinking about this. Maybe start here: https://gist.github.com/sevcsik/9207267

Comment: And based on this SO, I'm not sure if it is possible to load the module directly.  You may have to copy and paste code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710239/using-node-module-in-angularjs

Comment: This looks to be the most helpful: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/cross-platform-javascript/

Comment: In the specific case of scipy-node, you're going to have some serious issues modifying it to run in a browser, because [some of the module is written in Python](https://github.com/acjones617/scipy-node/tree/master/integrate/py), not JavaScript.

Comment: So it seems that using NodeJS modules with AngularJS isn't the most of ideal combinations... what would really be the best way to implement a NodeJS module's functionality into a web app? Thanks for all the help so far!